# how to make condition on update query

Tags: php, mysql

i made a query which which have a condition inside update.

```
UPDATE tbl_delivery SET amount_paid = 700000, amount_remaining = CASE WHEN 50000 < 700000 THEN 0 ELSE 50000 - 700000 END, transaction_status = IF(amount_remaining = 0, transaction_status = 'accepted', transaction_status='pending'), payment_status = CASE WHEN amount_remaining = 0 THEN payment_status = 'paid' ELSE payment_status = 'unpaid' END, modified = '2017-12-05 12:14:02' WHERE id = '1' AND user_id = '201720000003'

UPDATE tbl_delivery SET amount_paid = 700000, amount_remaining = CASE WHEN 50000 < 700000 THEN 0 ELSE 50000 - 700000 END, transaction_status = CASE WHEN amount_remaining = 0 THEN transaction_status = 'accepted' ELSE transaction_status = 'pending' END, payment_status = CASE WHEN amount_remaining = 0 THEN payment_status = 'paid' ELSE payment_status = 'unpaid' END, modified = '2017-12-05 12:01:17' WHERE id = '1' AND user_id = '201720000003'
```

this is the queries i test to get the right result but what happen is it is not getting the result that i wanted to get..

my problem lies on this field

```
    transaction_status = CASE WHEN amount_remaining = 0 THEN transaction_status = 'accepted' ELSE transaction_status = 'pending' END,
 transaction_status = IF(amount_remaining = 0, transaction_status = 'accepted', transaction_status='pending'),
```

instead of getting the result `accepted` or `pending` what i get was 0.

Comment: is this for mssql or mysql ?

Comment: it is already on the tag it is my sql..

Comment: then why include sql-server as a tag? ... do NOT add tags that are irrelevant, it does NOT help. *in fact it hinders*

Comment: opps.. my bad.. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you only need this:

```
transaction_status = CASE WHEN amount_remaining = 0 THEN 'accepted' ELSE 'pending' END
```

that is, you do not have to repeat "transaction_status ="

```
UPDATE tbl_delivery 
SET
        amount_paid = 700000
      , amount_remaining = CASE WHEN 50000 < 700000 THEN 0 ELSE 50000 - 700000 END
      , transaction_status = IF(amount_remaining = 0, 'accepted','pending')
      , payment_status = CASE WHEN amount_remaining = 0 THEN 'paid' ELSE 'unpaid' END
      , modified = '2017-12-05 12:14:02' 
WHERE id = '1' 
AND user_id = '201720000003'
```

Personally I prefer to use `case expressions` and I would not like to encourage use of IF() and CASE in the same query, which I think is just confusing.

Comment: but what is the reason it gets 0 instead of throwing error?.

Comment: i didn't use two condition inside one query.. that is the sample i made using two different queries..

Comment: I don't know because I have not had such a problem, nor do I have enough information to attempt a replication. One possible answer is you are getting zero meaning "false"